# Examples of $C^2(0,1)\cap C[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

I need examples of $C^2(0,1)\cap C[0,1]$. Are $x^2$ and $e^x$ examples. What is the importance of the closed interval $[0,1]$?

Comment: $C^2(0,1)\cap C[0,1]=\emptyset$ because the functions don't have the same domain. But there are functions in $C[0,1]$ whose restriction to $(0,1)$ are in $C^2(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

If by $u\in C^2(0,1)\cap C[0,1]$ you mean that $u:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $u$ restricted to the interval $(0,1)$ is $C^2$, then you can consider the function $u$ defined by $$u(x)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}$$

Note that $u$ is not in $C^2[0,1]$.

In partial differential equations it is common to see the space  $ C^2(0,1)\cap C[0,1]$. For example, in trying to solve the equation (for suitables $f$ and $g$)

$$\tag{1}
 \left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
 \Delta u=f &\mbox{ in $(0,1)$} \\
  u=g &\mbox{ in $\partial(0,1)$}
       \end{array} \right.
$$

a natural space to look for solutions is: $C^2(0,1)\cap C[0,1]$. This happens because we need two derivatives for the laplacian and if $g$ has some regularity on the boundary, we would expect that also $u$ has some regularity near the boundary (for example it is continuous).

Comment: You were inspired by the circle with center on $(\frac{1}{2},0)$ whose formula is $(x-\frac{1}{2})^2+y^2=(\frac{1}{2})^2$. The derivatives do not exist at the endpoints where the tangents become vertical. A similar function is $u(x)=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{1-x}$. Both functions become non-real outside $[0,1]$.

Comment: Yes you are right @JeppeStigNielsen. I like your example, it is so simple.

Comment: @Tomas: Could you show me why this is the case

Comment: Sorry @Vaolter, but I can't understand your qeustion> Could you be more specific?

Comment: @Tomás, I mean show why $u\in C^2(0,1)\cap C[0,1]$ but not in $C^2[0,1]$.

Comment: This is because the graph of $u$ is the upper part of the circle with center in $(1/2,0)$ and radius $1/2$, indeed, the tangent lines to the circle in the points $(1,0)$ and $(0,0)$ are parallel to the $y$-axis.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the function $x \, \mapsto \, x \sin(\frac{1}{x})$ which is continuous on $[0,1]$ and $\mathcal{C}^{2}$ on $]0,1[$.

Edit : (explanations)

> The function $x \, \mapsto \, x \sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is $\mathcal{C}^{2}$ on $]0,1[$ since it is the composition and product of functions which are $\mathcal{C}^{2}$ on $]0,1[$.
>
> From the inequality $\vert x \sin(\frac{1}{x}) \vert \leq \vert x \vert$, we deduce that $\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow 0} x \sin(\frac{1}{x}) = 0$. The function $x \, \mapsto \, x\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ which is defined on $]0,1]$ can be defined on $[0,1]$ by letting :
>
> $$
> f(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> x \sin(\frac{1}{x}) & \text{if } x \neq 0 \\
> 0 & \text{if } x =0 \\
> \end{cases}
> $$
>
> The function $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$. But the derivative of $f$ at $x=0$ doesn't exist. Consider $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ : we have
>
> $$ \frac{f(x)}{x} = \sin(\frac{1}{x}) $$
>
> $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ does not converge as $x \rightarrow 0$. So $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: Could you show me why this is the case.

Comment: I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

All polynomials, $\exp$, $\cos$, $\sin$ are in $C^\infty\left(\Bbb R\right)$. Also, for $f,g \in C^\infty\left(\Bbb R\right)$, $f+g\in C^\infty\left(\Bbb R\right)$, $fg\in C^\infty\left(\Bbb R\right)$ and $f\circ g \in C^\infty\left(\Bbb R\right)$. Then, you can restrict those functions to $[0,1]$ to get functions that are in $C^\infty[0,1]$ and whose restriction to $(0,1)$ are in $C^\infty(0,1)$ and therefore are examples of such functions.

---

To understand why having less smoothness on the slightly bigger interval is interesting, let's look at properties of functions $f:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ so that $f$ is $C^0$ on $[0,1]$ and $C^1$ on $(0,1)$ but $f$ is not $C^1$ on $[0,1]$. Since $f'$ is $C^0$ on $(0,1)$, we would be able to make $f$ $C^1$ on $(0,1)$ if we could extend $f'$ by continuity. Since we can't, at least one of the limits between $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f'(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}f'(x)$ does not exist. A classic example of such a function is $x\mapsto x\sin\frac{1}{x}$. The idea here is that when you differentiate it, you'll get a $\sin\frac{1}{x}$ term because of the product rule and it won't converge near $0$ since it won't have the $x$ factor to drag it towards $0$.

---

The one thing here you should remember is the example $x\mapsto x\sin\frac{1}{x}$ which helps to understand the necessity of most of the seemingly useless hypothesis of current real analysis theorems.